# Automatic Logout after 15 minutes of inactivity in clustered environment

Tags: java, jboss, cluster-computing

At present if the user logged into our application and the user is inactive for 15 mins i am redirecting the user to logout page. 
I am calculating the inactive by comparing *session.getLastAccessedTime()* and current time . It is working fine in the single server.
But in a clustered environment ( 3 jboss servers with load balancer ) it is not working . We are using Basic authentication mechanism.

How to implement automatically logging out the user after certain inactive time in the cluster as mentioned above?

Comment: Sounds like it should work. Have you made sure the clocks of the servers are synchronized? Where is the session stored? Is it shared between the servers?

Comment: Which version of JBoss are you using because it could have some specifics solutions. 
For wildfly 8.0 jboss servers: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/WildFly+8+Clustering+Howto#WildFly8ClusteringHowto-ClusterConfiguration. For previous versions, look the relative part of the official docs too. Especially TCP/UDP ports too, the jboss servers need that to be linked in order to work together.

Comment: we are using jboss 6 version. Session maintenance is done by application( its similar to bpm tool) .Server clocks are synchronized.

Comment: In our case session never get lost because every request has credetials to if no session found and new session is quickly created As we are using BASIC authentication